# ckeditor file browser

Tags: php, file-upload, ckeditor

I've lost the link to free file browser which can be integrated with ckeditor. It has the number '4' and `.NET` in the title and it's written in PHP.

Does anyone know the name of this program?

Answer (score 7):

I found it was easier to re-invent the wheel rather than to figure out how to integrate CKFinder - entirely possible that I'm just too thick.

Any way, see my code below. It's simple to understand and works well. While it does not allow users to navigate around in the server, it does allow you to indicate which directory to pull image files from when calling the browser.

It's all rather basic coding so it should work in all relatively modern browsers.

CKeditor merely opens a new window with the url provided

```
/*          
    in CKeditor **use encodeURIComponent()** to add dir param to the filebrowserBrowseUrl property

    Replace "content/images" with directory where your images are housed.
*/          
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {  
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'browse.php?type=Images&dir=' + encodeURIComponent('content/images'),  
            filebrowserUploadUrl: 'upload.php?type=Files&dir=' + encodeURIComponent('images') 
        });
```

### // =========  complete code below  for *browse.php*

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n");  
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate\n");  
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");  

// e-z params  
$dim = 150;         /* image displays proportionally within this square dimension ) */  
$cols = 4;          /* thumbnails per row */
$thumIndicator = '_th'; /* e.g., *image123_th.jpg*) -> if not using thumbNails then use empty string */  
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>browse file</title>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">  

    <style>  
        html,  
        body {padding:0; margin:0; background:black; }  
        table {width:100%; border-spacing:15px; }  
        td {text-align:center; padding:5px; background:#181818; }  
        img {border:5px solid #303030; padding:0; verticle-align: middle;}  
        img:hover { border-color:blue; cursor:pointer; }  
    </style>  

</head>  


<body>  

<table>  

<?php  

$dir = $_GET['dir'];    

$dir = rtrim($dir, '/'); // the script will add the ending slash when appropriate  

$files = scandir($dir);  

$images = array();  

foreach($files as $file){  
    // filter for thumbNail image files (use an empty string for $thumIndicator if not using thumbnails )
    if( !preg_match('/'. $thumIndicator .'\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i', $file) )  
        continue;  

    $thumbSrc = $dir . '/' . $file;  
    $fileBaseName = str_replace('_th.','.',$file);  

    $image_info = getimagesize($thumbSrc);  
    $_w = $image_info[0];  
    $_h = $image_info[1]; 

    if( $_w > $_h ) {       // $a is the longer side and $b is the shorter side
        $a = $_w;  
        $b = $_h;  
    } else {  
        $a = $_h;  
        $b = $_w;  
    }     

    $pct = $b / $a;     // the shorter sides relationship to the longer side

    if( $a > $dim )   
        $a = $dim;      // limit the longer side to the dimension specified

    $b = (int)($a * $pct);  // calculate the shorter side

    $width =    $_w > $_h ? $a : $b;  
    $height =   $_w > $_h ? $b : $a;  

    // produce an image tag
    $str = sprintf('<img src="%s" width="%d" height="%d" title="%s" alt="">',   
        $thumbSrc,  
        $width,  
        $height,  
        $fileBaseName  
    );  

    // save image tags in an array
    $images[] = str_replace("'", "\\'", $str); // an unescaped apostrophe would break js  

}

$numRows = floor( count($images) / $cols );  

if( count($images) % $cols != 0 )  
    $numRows++;  


// produce the correct number of table rows with empty cells
for($i=0; $i<$numRows; $i++)   
    echo "\t<tr>" . implode('', array_fill(0, $cols, '<td></td>')) . "</tr>\n\n";  

?>  
</table>  


<script>  

// make a js array from the php array
images = [  
<?php   

foreach( $images as $v)  
    echo sprintf("\t'%s',\n", $v);  

?>];  

tbl = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];  

td = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');  

// fill the empty table cells with the img tags
for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++)  
    td[i].innerHTML = images[i];  


// event handler to place clicked image into CKeditor
tbl.onclick =   

    function(e) {  

        var tgt = e.target || event.srcElement,  
            url;  

        if( tgt.nodeName != 'IMG' )  
            return;  

        url = '<?php echo $dir;?>' + '/' + tgt.title;  

        this.onclick = null;  

        // $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] was supplied by CKeditor
        window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?php echo $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum']; ?>, url);  

        window.close();  
    }  
</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/).  Built by the same people in a number of platforms including PHP.

Worth noting that a message is shown for the free download version when the file manager is displayed, a license key is required to hide the message (however the message is not really intrusive, no popups or anything).

Also, [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration) is the link for integrating CKFinder with CKEditor.

Edit: Alternatively, there is a completely free open source one [here](http://phpcamp.net/toolbar/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-30).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free one, the file-manager from the old FCKEditor, with instructions how to integrate it:
http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.roxyfileman.com - it's great and really easy to integrate. There are detailed instructions how to install and configure custom file browser to work with CKEditor.

Comment: No one should be using that file manager anymore. There are serious security vulnerabilities that are available online and the code is no longer updated so it probably won't get fixed.